# Bulk Movement Jobs in FileNet 5.2.1

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-content-engine

I have a requirement of moving documents from one storage area to another and planning to use Bulk Movement Jobs under Sweep Jobs in FileNet P8 v5.2.1.

My filter criteria is obviously (and only) the storage area id as I want to target a specific storage area and move the content to another storage area(kinda like archiving) without altering the security, relationship containment, document class etc.

When I run the job, though I have around 100,000 objects in the storage area that I am targeting; in examined objects field the job shows 500M objects and it took around 15hrs to move the objects. DBA analyze this situation to tell me that though I have all necessary indexes created on the docverion table(as per FileNet documentation), the job's still going for the full table scan.

1. Why would something like this happen?
2. What additional indexes can be used and how would that be helpful?
3. Is there a better way to do this with less time consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for 2 and 3 questions.

About indexes you can use this documentation https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.0/com.ibm.p8.performance.doc/p8ppt237.htm

You can improve the performance of your jobs if you split all documents  throught option "*Policy controlled batch size" (as i remember) at "Sweeps subsystem" tab in the Domain settings.

Use Time Slot management 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/p8pcc179.htm?lang=ru

and Filter Timelimit option
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNW2F_5.2.1/com.ibm.p8.ce.admin.tasks.doc/p8pcc203.htm?lang=ru

In commons you just split all your documents to the portions and process it in separated times and threads.

Comment: A quick question. Is there a way to find out exactly what are the db queries  fired during the bulk movement sweep job execution for a batch of objects from p8 trace logs?

Comment: @sin Yes, if you enable trace into P8 for DB operations, you will see all database queries.

Comment: appreciate you taking time to answer my queries. Will consider using these techniques and let you know the result.